# How do I (should I?) pass the context between UITableViews when using Core Data in a navigation based application?

Tags: uitableview, core-data, uinavigationcontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a navigation based application using Core Data and several levels of drill-down navigation. At the last level of the navigation I add records to the managed object store.At each level of navigation I create an array of view controllers for the next UITableView.

My question concerns the placement of the Core Data stack methods which create the managedObjectContext, managedObjectModel and the persistentStoreCoordinator.

Do I create these methods in the highest level view controller that needs to fetch data from the persistentStore and then pass a context object to the lower level viewcontrollers? Do I also need to pass a coordinator?

Many questions seem to point to putting these methods in the App Delegate but then many answers say "Do Not" put them in the app delegate. So where is the best place for these methods and which objects need to be passed to allow all necessary levels to fetch from the data store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First, some pre-requisites:

If you're building an application that uses Core Data, then you will *most probably* encounter situations where you will need to have more than one managed object context (MOC) around. You will however need one MOC that will "live" throughout the whole application session. Call that your main MOC *(since you'll be accessing it from the main thread only!!).*

More rarely and depending on your application, you may also encounter situations where you will need more than one NSPersistentStoreCoordinator. In my answer I will stick to the case where a single coordinator is required. As for your NSManagedObjectModel, that is entirely dependent on your application. Usually, you only need one of those.

#### To answer your questions:

I suggest having your main MOC be owned by the AppDelegate, since the latter is a singleton that lives for as long as the application lives. You can put the methods for creating/saving the main MOC in the AppDelegate, or delegate these tasks to a utility class. I find the second option a little cleaner, as you can use that utility class to add methods that create other MOCs on the fly, or to get a reference to the main MOC, from *any controller* in your application. That way, you avoid calling the AppDelegate all the time.

Note also, that if you already have a `NSManagedObject` in your hands, you can get the reference to the MOC that it's registered with, simply by calling `[yourManagedObject managedObjectContext]`. Once you have the MOC reference, you can get the associated `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and `NSManagedObjectModel` references. (This is to answer your question about "passing the coordinator": I prefer working with `NSManagedObject`s and the `NSManagedObjectContext` since they are at the top-most level of the abstraction, instead of passing around the coordinator or the model).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, the part about getting the context from the object makes good sense. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Apple puts the Core Data stack in the app delegate which works for the majority of cases.

It sounds to me like you are under utilizing Core Data. It sounds like your app design just uses Core Data to persist some data after you've gone down a hierarchy of views that are populated by arrays. Although you can get this work, you lose a lot of the automatic functionality of Core Data.

Core Data is not primarily about saving data. Instead it is an API for creating the model layer in a Model-View-Controller design app. As such, Core Data usually comprises the actual logical "guts" of the application. Apple puts the stack in the app delegate because it is assumed that Core Data will be used throughout the app.

In the standard design, you would use Core Data to populate all your views so you would need Core Data at the top an bottom of any hierarchy.

Comment: I started the application just calling a SQLite database that stored all the application data. At the moment I have sqllite spread throughout the app and core data just added to track user data. I need to refactor the whole app to use Core Data. Thanks for your suggestions.